# UINavigationController with two delegates?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Suppose I have a UINavigationController upon which I want to perform custom transitions. For convenience, I define a transition class:

```
class WTPTransition: NSObject
{
    // This is our Interaction Controller, which conforms to UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning. Apple's concrete class suits our needs.
    var interactionController : UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition?
}

extension WTPTransition : UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning
{
    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 1
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let toView   = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)!.view!
        let fromView = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)!.view!

        transitionContext.containerView.insertSubview(toView, belowSubview: fromView)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), animations: {
            fromView.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: { finished in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
        })
    }
}
```

Then I extend it so that I can simply set a UINavigationController's `delegate` property and get my transitions:

```
extension WTPTransition : UINavigationControllerDelegate
{
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, interactionControllerFor animationController: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        return interactionController
    }
}
```

Which works well enough, but what happens if I want another class to observe that same navigation controller's events? I cannot have two objects as its delegate, so what is the correct pattern to use? It seems natural to decouple something like transition logic from observing controllers being shown or dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is very dirty architecture.

1. An animation it is object that needed only while transition is active.
2. You should have ability to change animation for some viewControllers.

I think you can create delegate class, that will create animations for appearing and disappearing.